# Php page data as a notification in Android

Tags: php, android, xampp

I want to pass data from a table in xampp as a notification.

My current code is:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Reminder");
mBuilder.setContentText("Please take your medicines!");
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(++FcmMessagingService.id, mBuilder.build());`
```

Here, instead of the given ContentTitle and ContentText I would like to fetch data from a table and display it.

Is that possible?

Comment: yes. it is possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Make a http request to your api

Comment: Can you help me with any link maybe?

Comment: here you go mate...https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Umm.. that not what i want, I want it as a notification

Comment: try **FCM**, check this https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-android/